# How to manage multiple api calls in react Flux App

Tags: api, reactjs, flux

So i have an Api wich serves reports by "hourOfDay"

```
http://localhost:8080/api/v1/reports/61?aggregation=hourOfDay&start=2016-02-10T00:00:00.000Z&stop=2016-02-20T10:59:59.000Z
```

In my React App i want to display this and the previous time range. That needs to do an other call to that endpoint in order to compare them in a graph.

```
http://localhost:8080/api/v1/reports/61?aggregation=hourOfDay&start=2016-02-20T00:00:00.000Z&stop=2016-02-30T10:59:59.000Z
```

So how would i do that?

Would i have one Service - Action - Store -Component combination. Like that the service gets called and it triggers two api calls, wait for both and passes then both to the action and than to the store, so the component can access all the data at the same time? Or how would i solve this? I mean i could change the api endpoint but i want it as clean as possible and i guess the single report endpoint is needed elsewhere later on...

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use a series. Action -> Api.get -> Api.onGot -> Action -> Store -> Action -> Api.get -> Api.onGot -> Action -> Store and refresh.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think caching the first result in the store might be a good practice. But I'm not sure if it is the right way to trigger actions from a store. So i wonder if you got me more details why you would do it and/or any other stuff like blogposts that i can read through?

Comment: I use reflux so there haven't run into any issues triggering an action from a store. Here is an article about publish/subscribe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I think the better way is your View call an Action that call the 2 API requests. The first called request redirect the result for the nested request.

See this pseudocode:

YourView:

```
// this function is called when the result2 is dispatched.
// you can get the information from the Store
function receiveResultFromTimeRange () {
    console.log(YourStore.getResult2());
},

// listening for the result2
function componentDidMount () {
    YourStore.addChangeListener(this.receiveResultFromTimeRange);
    YourAction.timeRange(parameter1);
}
```

YourAction:

```
return {

    // you can call only the second request in this way
    request2: function(parameter2) {
        new RequestService().secondRequest(result1).done(function (result2) {
            Dispatcher.dispatch({
                method: 'receiveResultFromSecondRequest',
                result: result2
            });
        });
    },

    // call the first request and use the result to call the second request
    request1And2: function(parameter1){
        new RequestService().firstRequest(parameter1).done(function (result1) {
            this.request2(result1);
        });
    }
}
```

YourStore:

```
var _result2 = null;

receiveResultFromSecondRequest: function (result2) {
    // save result2 in the Store, LocalStorage... whatever you want.
    _result2 = result2;
    this.emit(SUCCESS_SECOND_REQUEST);
},

addChangeListener: function (callback) {
    this.addListener(SUCCESS_SECOND_REQUEST, callback);
},

getResult2: function(){
    return _result2;
}
```